# Pitch accent of "たくさんの人"

Tags: pitch-accent

I am trying to parse the pitch accent of the bolded phrase in the following sentence:

> 毎日、**たくさんの人が**秋夫の船にのります

The word たくさん has pitch taKUSAn, while the word 人 has pitch "hiTO" (with the "hi" devoiced).  But according to prosody, the pitch of the full word (with particle) "たくさんの人が" comes out to "taKUSANNOHITOga":

> [image]

It's as if the whole phrase is odaka. Moreover, if I try to force prosody to parse the phrase as "taKUSAn no hiTO GA", it gives me an error:

> [image]

Is prosody correct? If so, what's going on?

Comment: [Google翻訳's result](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ja&tl=en&text=%E6%AF%8E%E6%97%A5%E3%80%81%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%95%E3%82%93%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%8C%E7%A7%8B%E5%A4%AB%E3%81%AE%E8%88%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AE%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99&op=translate&hl=ja) (たくさんのひとが【LHHLLLHL】) sounds more accurate to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OJAD's Suzuki-kun/Prosody is simply wrong. It often is.

The correct accent is たくさ＼んのひと＼が (aka たくさんのひとが{LHHLLLHL}, though the と will be lower than the さ due to terracing, which is not possible to represent with this site's LH notation)

Namely:

- たくさん is [3] and stays [3] regardless of whether it's followed by の or not (unlike 日本 for example, which will turn from [2] into [0] when followed by の).
- ひと is [0] standalone, but when modified by a proceeding phrase, it becomes [2] (odaka).

Comment: I've heard before that the switch of 日本 from [2] to [0] when followed by の is only optional. So are you saying it is in fact not and instead always happens? Also, with your second point you mean that something like 人を見る is [ひとをみる]{LHHHL} instead of [ひとをみる]{LHLHL}, is that correct?

Comment: @Kaskade You do sometimes hear 日本 as [2] before の but it generally sounds emphasized and is not that common. I'd say the switch to [0] is pretty regular/strong. And yes 人を見る if standalone would be ひとをみる{LHHHL}. Perhaps 人を呼ぶ (ひとを{LHH}よぶ{LH}) would be a more canonical standalone usage.